# QTrayIcon segfault

Tags: c++, qt

In my code i tried to connect signal from QTrayIcon object and my form in such way:

```
connect(m_trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),
    this, SLOT(iconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
```

But i received a segfault on this code. Any ideas?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is `m_trayIcon` a valid object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this can't be the reason for the segfault, Qt does not segfault if a signal or a slot is not existant, it will give you conseole warnings when it happens to not find a signal and/or slot which you used.

So you should take a deeper look where the segfault comes from. Maybe, as allready pointed ou, m_trayIcon is not setup properly aka dangling pointer.

Example of QTrayIcon usage: http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/desktop-systray.html

Comment: Sure, you're right, i was trying to connect tray icon before i initialized it %))))